# How to get type of returned value from callback in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, types

I have a code that goes like this:

```js
validateViaTransaction(
  id: string,
  datas: any,
  callback: <T> (t: firestore.Transaction, data: any) => Promise<T>
) => {
  return await firestore().
   runTransaction(async t => {
    get someting...

    validate something and throw err...

    return await callback(t, data);

   }).catch(err => { throw err; });
}
```

now when I try to use later:

```js
await validateViaTransaction(id, null, (t: firestore.Transaction) => {
 t.set(new data here...., {merge: true});

 return "Validation Successful";
})
```

now as I check the return type of the code it is **Promise`<unknown>`**

and when I implement it in the code the error goes like this.

```
Argument of type '(t: Transaction) => string' is not assignable to parameter of type '<T>(t: Transaction, data: any) => T'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T'.
    'string' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{}'.ts(2345)
```

Is there any way to make my `callback` function **more like generic-ish**? like after I return **`string`** then its type would also be **`string`**

Comment: You're using `await` over `callback`, whose return type is `T`. Is there any reason for using await on it? if so, your callback should return a `Promise<T>` and your callback should be `async (t: firestore.Transaction): Promise<string>`

Comment: @briosheje yes, since I passed the `t`, which in turn might still use the `t.get`,

Comment: then the result signature should be `Promise<T>`.

Comment: yep, it's a typo, will update it.

Comment: anyway, yoou should check this: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30496

Comment: tried using it's type but another error occured. Generic type 'CallbackType' requires 1 type argument(s).

Comment: the issue is that you just **can't** use `string` in that context as a generic `T`, since `string` is a primitive. You should normalize the output of that signature or just provide `Promise<any>` as the response type.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have your generics in the wrong place, but I can't get your code to compile at all since I don't have firebase in my environment.  If you'd like to increase your chances of getting a targeted answer, please consider editing your code into a [mcve] with no external dependencies (either include the relevant types in your code, or replace them with toy versions that still show your issue) so we can drop your code into any IDE and figure it out without installing other stuff. ... or, barring that, give a link to a web IDE with those dependencies already in place.   Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You are calling callback like: `return await callback(t, data);`

By using `await` `callback` is expected to return a `Promise` (you can only await promises)

You need to adjust your signature for this:

```
callback: <T> (t: firestore.Transaction, data: any) => Promise<T>
```

By using `async` on function, it will automatically be wrapped in a promise.

So you should call it like this:

```
await validateViaTransaction(id, null, async (t: firestore.Transaction) => {
 t.set(new data here...., {merge: true});

 return "Validation Successful";
})
```

with the async, the callback will now return a `Promise<string>`

Comment: tried it but the error is just about the same,

```
Type 'Promise<string>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<T>'
```